# How to update/change object in array?

Tags: javascript

I have array with object in localstorage
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jx7x.png)

Some a function return object with new data. I need to write new data to object in localstorage (identify by ID).

I tried but... See my code below

```
      const result = {
        type: 'mobile',
        id: 'tsy152ivm',
        score: 55
      }

      const links = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('links'));
      const item = links.find(item => item.id === result.id);
      //localStorage.setItem('links', JSON.stringify(item));
```

Comment: please include your complete code, the current code is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the object you want to modify, and use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to update the object's properties.

```js
let arr = [{id: 34, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 'tsy152ivm', name: 'Sam'}]

const result = {
        type: 'mobile',
        id: 'tsy152ivm',
        score: 55
      }

const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.id === result.id);

const updated = [...arr.slice(0, index),Object.assign({}, arr[index], { id: result.id, name: 'Samantha' }),
...arr.slice(index + 1)
]

console.log(updated);
```

or just modify the object directly, using an index.

```js
let arr = [{id: 34, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 'tsy152ivm', name: 'Sam'}]

const result = {
        type: 'mobile',
        id: 'tsy152ivm',
        score: 55
      }

const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.id === result.id);


arr[index] = Object.assign({}, arr[index], { name: 'Samantha'})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get data from the storage, find an index of the target item, merge old object with a new one and store the result at the specific index, and then set the whole array at the same key. Here is a part of the most important steps:

```
const newData = {
  id: 'ID_2',
  NEW_DATA: 'NEW_DATA'
};

/**
 * Get old data from storage
 */

const dataFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('links'));

/**
 * Merge old object with a new one (find by ID)
 */

const index = dataFromStorage.findIndex(d => d.id === newData.id);
dataFromStorage[index] = Object.assign({}, dataFromStorage[index], newData)

/**
 * Update full array in storage
 */

localStorage.setItem('links', JSON.stringify(dataFromStorage));
```

And here is a link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g57uaenL/3/) with fully working example (check the local storage after execution).